# “How much petrol costs” or “How much costs petrol”? Or are both wrong?

Tags: word-order

I am very not sure what is correct one,

> How much petrol costs

or

> How much costs petrol

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context.

One could ask "How much does petrol cost?"

Or one could ask "Do you know how much petrol costs?" (See Kate Bunting)

Or one could state "Petrol costs $1.45/gallon."

Or--rather awkwardly--"$1.35/gallon is how much petrol costs."

As a note, people in the US say "gas" or "gasoline" instead of petrol, but they will know what you are saying either way.

Comment: _"How much petrol costs" is always wrong._ Not necessarily. "Do you know how much petrol costs?"

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking a question, you usually need an auxiliary (helper) verb before the subject. There are a few typical ones, e.g.:

- ***Can** we **get** some petrol?* (modal)
- ***Have** you **bought** some petrol recently?* (present perfect form)
- *Why **are** you **stopping** for petrol?* (present continuous form)

If you're not using one of those (or *be*, as in *how expensive **is** petrol now?*) we use *do* to form a question:

- *How much **does** petrol **cost**?*

The main verb (*cost*) is the infinitive form instead, and *do* is the verb that gets conjugated:

- *How much **did** petrol cost thirty years ago?* (simple past, subject is 3rd-person)
- *How much **do** you earn?* (simple present, subject is 2nd-person)